# How to keep application awake in flutter?

Tags: flutter

How to keep an application from locking the screen in flutter?

Is there a flag to turn it off an on? Does flutter SDK expose this?

Something like `keepAwake(true);`

Answer (score 130, accepted):

Note: This package [wakelock](https://pub.dev/packages/wakelock) has some depedencies conflicts with other packages. Use this [wakelock_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/wakelock_plus)instead. click on [Reference](https://github.com/creativecreatorormaybenot/wakelock/issues/220)
As support for the [screen plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/screen) that [@Tree](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4211520) mentioned has been discontinued and there are some issues with it now, you can use **[`wakelock`](https://pub.dev/packages/wakelock)**.
Full disclosure: I am the author of this plugin, however, it is basically a port of the wakelock functionality from the `screen` plugin, with the issues fixed:

```dart
import 'package:wakelock/wakelock.dart';

// To keep the screen on:
Wakelock.enable(); // or Wakelock.toggle(on: true);

// To let the screen turn off again:
Wakelock.disable(); // or Wakelock.toggle(on: false);
```

[Learn more.](https://pub.dev/packages/wakelock#-readme-tab-)

Comment: Where should I add Wakelock.enable() ? I want it on everypage of my application

Comment: Is this still recommended in 2021? I.e. do we really need a third party plugin for something that common?!? Doesn't Flutter provide something?

Comment: @SePröbläm Hi, I am still maintaining it :) We recently added **macOS** support as well  Also, Flutter is open source - they have first-party plugins, however, they do say themselves that they will abandon their first-party solutions if a better third party project exists. So why would they want to create one for something that works perfectly fine?

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot Good to know. Thank you very much for providing it!

Comment: I assume this keeps the app running in the background and you can play, for example as well a sound like a "RINGRINGRING" - is it possible to turn on the screen as well somehow?

Comment: @AlexSemeniuk That has nothing to do with the display.

Answer (score 62):

I found plugin that does the job.
https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/screen

```
import 'package:screen/screen.dart';

// Prevent screen from going into sleep mode:
Screen.keepOn(true);
```

You also need to set permission for android

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Comment: Now that's called a Stackoverflow spirit, instead of updating yours, you accepted someone else answer :D

Comment: @user6274128 Just because of doing this I gave both of them an upvote!

Comment: Wakelock can be used without any permission. More at https://pub.dev/packages/wakelock

Answer (score 6):

This package does the work
https://pub.dev/packages/wakelock

*It depends on Flutter [Wakelock class](https://pub.dev/documentation/wakelock/latest/wakelock/Wakelock-class.html).*

**Permissions**
The wakelock plugin does not require any permissions on any platform.
This is because it only enables the screen wakelock and not any partial (CPU) wakelocks that would keep the app alive in the background.

**How to Use it?**

```
// to enable the Android and iOS wakelock
Wakelock.enable();

// to disables the wakelock again.
Wakelock.disable();



import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:wakelock/wakelock.dart';


void main() {
  runApp( MyApp());
}


class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Wakelock.enable(); // Here :)
    return MaterialApp(
      home:  MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}
```

Note: You have to Stop and Run again

Answer (score 5):

As @creativecreatorormaybenot already answered, you can use wakeLock to keep the screen on. But I wanted to add where to put the `Wakelock.enable();`.
Here a code snippet how I used it and it works fine for me:

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Wakelock.enable();
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: MainScreen()
    );
  }
}
```

I hope it will fix your problem. Here is the link to the package: https://pub.dev/packages/wakelock

Comment: [wakelock: ^0.5.6,] (https://pub.dev/packages/wakelock) yes it does the job very well