# Is there a wakelock in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter

I'm using Flutter dev version 1.7.8
is there a way to keep screen always on? 
I've been googling a lot on this and this is the only thing I've found [How to keep application awake in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49684463/how-to-keep-application-awake-in-flutter) 
But this plugin doesn't work anymore. The last release was almost a year ago, I suppose there were some breaking changes in flutter during this time

It's not an option for me to write my own plugin for it right now

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to keep application awake in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49684463/how-to-keep-application-awake-in-flutter)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Alternative

Full disclosure: Due to issues I was having with the `screen` plugin, I created a plugin ([`wakelock`](https://pub.dev/packages/wakelock)) for wakelock exclusively. More on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56918918/6509751).

### Fixing `screen`

The plugin you mentioned, i.e. [`screen`](https://pub.dev/packages/screen) does still work. You will just have to migrate it to AndroidX in Android Studio when running on Android (open the `android` module in Android Studio and use `Refactor -> Migrate to AndroidX`).

There are a few [open pull requests](https://github.com/clovisnicolas/flutter_screen/pulls).
An alternative to manually migrating to AndroidX would be making use of one of the pull requests and using a `git` dependency in your `pubspec.yaml` instead:

```
dependencies:
  screen:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/clovisnicolas/flutter_screen
      ref: 496b60ac1acbc3d5e8400bb2032c5c9d7e46d4c7
```

If you still cannot get it to work, let me know and I might publish a fixed version of this plugin or a wake lock only plugin.