# Flutter: Wake up phone screen for alarm

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile

I'm implementing an alarm application for Android with Flutter. With the *android_alarm_manager* package, I'm able to create and receive alarms. Furthermore, the package *bringtoforeground* is useful to bring the application to foreground when using another app. However, I haven't found a way to wake up the phone screen, yet. Does anybody knows how to do that? Also, It should be possible to have the application open without entering a password or something comparable.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to keep application awake in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49684463/how-to-keep-application-awake-in-flutter)

Comment: No, I do want the phone to sleep during night and having it waken up in the morning

Answer (score 0):

I've found an answer to my question. Additionally to the two packages said, there is a modification to be made in the *AndroidManifest.xml* file. Two more properties are needed in the activity tag as follows:

```
<activity
  android:showWhenLocked="true"
  android:turnScreenOn="true">
```

Comment: what did you do using Flutter to wake up your device?