# Is it possible to keep our flutter application awake when it has opened a page with Flutter Web Browser (In App Browser)?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, inappbrowser, flutter-web-browser

I've an application in which I need to open some Interactive HTML5 content pages in `flutter_web_browser`. The feature works fine, but now I've requirement of stopping devices from going to `sleep` on these pages. I already tried solution mentioned over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49684463/how-to-keep-application-awake-in-flutter). But that only works for app and not when these content pages are visited.

Anyone has any idea of accomplishing that or some workaroud?

Remember if I try to render those pages via WebView, the behavior becomes unpridictable in several devices. And even for IOS most of the times it doesn't work.

**Please note that I can't render that content in WebView, because that has lot of issues.**

The code that opens these pages look like below:

```
Future<dynamic> getPlatformBrowserWidget(String url) async {
    if (Platform.isIOS)
      return FlutterWebBrowser.openWebPage(
        url: url,
        safariVCOptions: SafariViewControllerOptions(
          barCollapsingEnabled: true,
          preferredBarTintColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
          preferredControlTintColor: Colors.white,
          dismissButtonStyle: SafariViewControllerDismissButtonStyle.close,
          modalPresentationCapturesStatusBarAppearance: false,
        ),
      );
    else
      return FlutterWebBrowser.openWebPage(
        url: url,
        customTabsOptions: CustomTabsOptions(
          colorScheme: CustomTabsColorScheme.dark,
          toolbarColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
          secondaryToolbarColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
          navigationBarColor: Colors.white,
          addDefaultShareMenuItem: false,
          instantAppsEnabled: true,
          showTitle: false,
          urlBarHidingEnabled: true,
        ),
      );
  }
```